# How to get all values of combobox in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, combobox

I want to get all values of combobox not only selected value.
example:

> $price = array('100','200','300');
>   echo $this->form->create('Price_form',array('url'=>array('controller'=>'Sale','action'=>'sale')));
>   echo $this->form->input('Price', array('type'=>'select','options'=>$price));
>   echo $this->form->end();

In SaleController:

> $post_data = $this->request->data['Price_form']['Price'];

If so,I get only selected value.Now,I want to get all values such as: 100,200,300..
My Cakephp version is 2.5.7.
If know ways,help me plz...!

Comment: Why? ps, please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Comment: cakephp version is 2.5.7

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible like this.

You should passed to the view from Controller and you will have it.

In controller:

```
$price=array(100,200,300);
$this->set('price',$price);
```

And in your view

```
echo $this->form->input('Price', array('type'=>'select','options'=>$price));
```

this is the only way that i see

Answer (score 0):

Define your options in controller rather than view and then have them straight away from controller rather than from posted data

In controller

```
$prices = array(100, 200, 300);

    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
        $postedPrices = $this->request->data['Price_form']['Price']; // Selected Prices
        $allPrices = $prices; // All price options
    }

    $this->set(compact('prices')); // Set prices for view
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try to pass it in a hidden input field:
(Did not test this)

View:

```
 $price = array('100','200','300');
 ...
 $allPricesAsString = implode(',',$price);
 $form->input('allPrices', array('value'=>$allPricesAsString,'type' => 'hidden'));
```

Controller:

```
 $allPrices = explode(',',$this->request->data['Price_form']['allPrices']);
```

But I actually do not understand why you would set the data in the view.
Usually you should do this in the controller like it was said before.